How to split a file .tex into several different file .tex?
Hi I'm writing a file with 15.000+ lines and I need to separate them into several files .txt so that they can be compiled independently so as not to have to compile the large file every time.
I did this
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}
\input{Impostazioni.txt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{ProvaSimbologia.tex}
\end{document}

Where "Impostazioni.txt" is a file only with the
\usepackage{...}
\definecolor{...}
\newcommand{...}
etc...

and similar things (no \begin{docoment} and \end{document})
"Simbologia.tex" is a self-contained, compileable LaTeX file
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{...}
\definecolor{...}
\newcommand{...}
etc...
\begin{document}
\chapter{Simbologia}
***words***
\end{document}

The compilator gives me this error
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.


I don't understand what's wrong. However, if I include only the "ProvaSimbologia" file in the file it compiles it for me. Would anyone be able to help me?

You cannot have two \documentclass in the same file. In your master where you want to input or include Simbologia.tex, make sure to also load fx the docmute package, it changes \input and friends, such that everything from \documentclass to \begin{document} and from \end{document} and down is ignored.

There is also the subfiles packages that offers similar functionality.

Thank you very much!
